# Принцип инверсии зависимостей. Абстракция и реализация на одном уровне или же абстракция с его собственным модулем?

Tags: inversion-of-control

В книге "Внедрение зависимостей на платформе .NET", пишут:

> принцип инверсии зависимостей диктует обязательное распространение
> абстракций с их собственными модулями

В других книгах (например "Чистая архитектура") и статьях об этом ничего не упоминается, а лишь пишут, что более низкие уровни могут использовать абстракции уровней выше.

А теперь пример:

У меня есть абстракция сервиса и его реализация на одном сервисном уровне (или его называют уровень приложения). И эта абстракция используется на уровне пользовательского интерфейса (UI). Если судить правилу, которое написано в книге "Внедрение зависимостей на платформе .NET", то это считается ошибкой, ведь, абстракция используется в UI и значит находится она должна там же (я знаю, что теперь сервисный уровень будет зависеть от UI, но сейчас не об этом). Но в чем проблема, что абстракция и реализация лежат на одном уровне? Мы же следуем правилу, что более низкие уровни должны зависеть от уровней выше, и просто на уровне UI используем абстракцию, которая лежит на одном уровне с реализацией.

Comment: Поменьше следуйте  всем догматам.

Comment: @avp, я не озабочен ни паттернами ни догматами, использую только то, что считаю нужным и необходимым. Сейчас я пытаюсь разобраться с данной "проблемой", которая не дает мне покоя из-за интереса. Для себя я сделал вывод, что правило в книге "Внедрение зависимостей на платформе .NET" - вредный совет, который только больше путает. Но вдруг я не прав и это правило несет в себе какой-то смысл?

Comment: Все правила имеют смысл только в определенных ситуациях. В других они либо бессмысленны, либо вредны. К сожалению, очень многие авторы книг, рассказывая о каком-либо правиле, склонны либо абсолютизировать его, либо не вдаваться в анализ множества ситуаций когда это правило в самом деле хорошо работает

Comment: Кстати, интересно, какой-такой небоскреб вы строите, что вынуждены вообще вводить абстракции сервиса?

Comment: Я не строю небоскреб, это просто пример из воздуха. А что такого, чтобы использовать интерфейс для реализаций в сервисном уровне? Как минимум для модульного тестирования. В сервисном уровне реализуются транзакционные сценарии или активная запись, в связи с этим можно внедрить не основную реализацию, а какой-нибудь декоратор, чтобы посмотреть или реализовать функционал, который позволит выполнить действия ДО и ПОСЛЕ транзакции (это пример с ходу). Интерфейсы не обязательны в объектах DTO или тому подобных, у которых нету поведений, но в сервисе есть поведения

Comment: Если это посто упражнение такое, то ничего плохого нет, только польза для развития. Плохо, когда подобные практики становятся повсеместными. В результате мы имеем то, что имеем -- никаких гигагерц и гигабайт уже не хватает для показа нескольких килобайт текста на экране (в высоком разрешении)